# How to prevent users from visiting Deleted action method directly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

**Scenario:**

Clicking a delete hyperlink on one product of a product list will invoke `/Product/Delete` HttpGet action method. The user then clicks the confirmation button to invoke  `/Product/Delete` HttpPost action method which in turn redirect the user to `/Product/Deleted` HttpGet action method.

I want to prevent users from skipping `/Product/Delete` and  directly invoking `/Product/Deleted`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before redirecting put something into `TempData`. Then in the `Deleted` action verify if this something is present in the `TempData`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete()
{
    // TODO: Delete
    TempData["deleted"] = true;
    return RedirectToAction("deleted");
}

public ActionResult Deleted()
{
    if(TempData["deleted"] == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "not found");
    }
    return View();
}
```

You should be aware that there is a price to pay with this. If the user presses <kbd>F5</kbd> while browsing the `/product/deleted` action he will get 404. So basically what you are trying to do is bad design and I would recommend you avoiding it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out here that when you're performing actions that cause a change in state, POST should be used in preference of GET. Using this form of seperation will benefit you in the long run.

Comment: @Darin, I think we should set `TempData["deleted"]` to `null` prior to `return View()` in `Deleted()` to avoid multiple invocation?

Comment: @xport, no you don't need setting it null. It will automatically be null on subsequent calls. That's how TempData works. It's automatically invalidated. That's the reason why I pointed out that if the user presses F5 to refresh he will get 404 because the TempData will be invalidated.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon, that's what's used here. Notice the `[HttpPost]` attribute on the `Delete` action.

Comment: @Darin, one question more: If you setup `TempData` in `HttpPost Delete()` and redirect to `/Product/Deleted`, it means redirection causes the server notify the browser to make a GET request to `/Product/Deleted`, right? How the server maintains the `TempData`?

Comment: @xport, correct, TempData is maintained for a single redirect or more precisely a single request following the one that stored something into TempData.

Comment: @Darin, I was backing up your point and pointing out the use of POST and GET as a more formal pattern. Knowing when to use either/or is fairly important to a good architecture (as you already know).

Comment: @Darin, I think it is better to redirect the user to a certain page rather than issuing HttpException whenever the TempData==null.

Comment: @xport: I think you should just redirect to the Delete page if TempData is null, thus giving them a chance to confirm it.

Comment: @Brian: If `TempData["deleted"]` is `null` and I redirect to `Delete` action method and the item has not found, what should I do? From the `HttpGet Delete` action method, I return a `not found confirmation` view or redirect to a `not found` action method?

Comment: @RecyleBin: That's a UI decision, not a coding decision.  I suggest either finding similar online applications and mimicking their workflow or asking for direction from someone who does design work for your company.